# php regex matching a characters that is not preceded by a specific character

Tags: php, regex

I have a string where there are sections with double quotes.Im trying to replace all the double quotes with single quotes except ones that have escaping ie: `\"`.

I'm trying to build a regex that matches all `"` except ones that comes like `\"`

So when I use `preg_replace` I will get as follows.

```
"love" -> 'love'

"John said \"HI\"" - > 'John said \"HI\"'
```

I have tried the following which does exactly the opposite.

```
[<^\\]"
```

Comment: simple note: you won't be able to detect specifically escaped `"` in `"John said \"HI\""`, the "\" is not in the string anymore. If not escaped, on the contratry, it would be a syntax error. Or maybe do you have `"John said \\\"HI\\\""`?

Comment: @Jan This question is an evident duplicate, there is a good solution already, why not close? Your answer is incorrect anyway.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Why should it be incorrect? Btw, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952713/regex-pattern-matching-takes-a-long-time-for-strings-with-length-more-than-30-ch) with your answer having four upvotes so far has been asked a zillion times on SO (problem is the backtracking), why not close this as well?

Comment: @Jan Backtracking related questions are never evident. If you find a question with the identical pattern, I will close that question. Your solution here does not account for escaped backslashes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: A search for ["regex takes long time"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regex+takes+long+time) reveals [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36864281/regex-takes-a-long-time-to-complete) (btw. answered by you), [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7464895/regex-taking-a-long-time) and [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41864096/why-does-this-regular-expression-take-a-long-time-to-run).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: The last one was marked as an exact duplicate of [**this one**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982466/why-does-this-take-so-long-to-match-is-it-a-bug) - all of them have a good explanation on catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Concerning your other point: my answer does not account for escaped backslashes but this was not a requirement. See, I know that you are brilliant in regular expressions and programming in general but sometimes I find the decisions on closing a bit incomprehensible - after all, at least two thirds of the underlying mechanisms of  the questions have been asked before on SO.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew even though my use case here is  a escaped double quote.my question is general.The accepted answer can be applied to any similar account.

Comment: @ShalithaVikum You should be aware that a plain lookbehind approach [does not let you match valid unescaped quotes if they are preceded with a literal backslash](https://regex101.com/r/2WNJDN/1) (represented in the string literal with two consecutive backslashes). So, the solution you accepted will not work for a general case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a neg. lookbehind:

```
(?<!\\)"
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/T6svPv/1).

---

In `PHP`:

```
<?php

$strings = ['"love"', '"John said \"HI\""'];

$regex = '~(?<!\\\\)"~';

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    echo preg_replace($regex, "'", $string) . "\n";
}

?>
```

This yields

```
'love'
'John said \"HI\"'
```

Be aware though that the backslash needs to be escaped as well in `PHP`, so that you'll need four backslashes in total here.

Comment: Thanks, Jan.Appreciated.